# Look for advice on data design for postgres and rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm somewhat new to database design, and I'm looking for suggestions for an efficient way to store what months a flower blooms.  The problem that I'm coming up against is that there is no standard.  Some flowers might bloom for one month, other might bloom for multiple months, and still others might bloom at two different times.  The two basic formats I've come up with are 1) one field where each relevant month is hand entered and comma separated "Mar, Apr, Sep, Oct" and 2) individual columns for each month possibly being linked to a table for each month).

I guess I'm wondering if there are any better ways to do this?  In addition to displaying the months that a flower blooms, I'd like to display what flowers are blooming for which months.  I understand how to do with with 13 tables, but it seems like such a s waste.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in months, I would suggest a table `BlossomingMonths` that has two columns, one for the flower and the second for the month.  If a flower blossoms for multiple months there would be multiple rows in the table.

Both your solutions are troublesome.  SQL is not particularly good at string manipulation, so storing values in a string can pose problems.  Postgres has nice extensions for arrays and JSON, but I would go with the standard SQL method of a separate row per flower/month.The second method is also troublesome.  To get flowers that blossom for only one method requires looking at all 12 columns.

That said, I can see a lot of challenges with trying to capture this information.  In particular, the blossoming period varies by location -- both latitude and altitude.  So, some sort of geographic indicator might also be useful.

If this a for particular plans in a particular location, I would go with two fields, a date when the flower started blooming and a date when the blooming ends.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. A bit more background might be helpful - this is an inventory for a specific garden (we're looking at 3000+ plants) so geographic location is not an issue, though each plant does need a unique record.  I hand't thought about doing a start/end entry, and guess I could enter a second one.  The other idea that just came to mind is a binary format (001100001100 to represent bloom times in Mar, Apr, Sep, Oct).

Comment: @Ben . . . No, don't do that!  Unless you have a real reason for storing the data cryptically, store it so it makes sense and is easy to use.